# Saving objects related through many to many fields throwing field error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have some models that are inter-related through various relations, including M2M relations.
I have overridden create methods of 2 of the model's serializers so that I can create all the related objects through one post. But it keeps throwing the following error when i try to create object through doctor serializer :-

```
{
  "permissions": {
    "ui_element": [
      "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received UIElement."
    ]
  },
  "hospital": [
    "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received Hospital."
  ]
}
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to solve this.
Here's my models.py

```
class StaffPermissions(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    This table stores all the permissions that each staff has
    fields:
    - {ui_element}: foreign key to UIElement table
    - {create}: boolean field to store if the staff has create permission
    - {read}: boolean field to store if the staff has read permission
    - {update}: boolean field to store if the staff has update permission
    - {delete}: boolean field to store if the staff has delete permission
    """

    ui_element = models.ForeignKey(UIElement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    create = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    update = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class HospitalDoctor(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    This talbe stores all the information related to staff and their roles for a given hospital
    fields:
    - {hospital}: foreign key to Hospital table
    - {doctor}: foreign key to Doctor table
    - {role}: integer field to store the role of the staff
    - {is_visible}: boolean field to store if the staff is visible on the UI
    - {is_deleted}: boolean field to store if the staff is deleted/removed
    - {permissions}: many to many field to store the permissions of the staff for each UI element
    """

    ROLES = (
        (2, "HOSPITALADMIN"),
        (3, "HOSPITALOWNER"),
        (4, "DEPARTMENTHEAD"),
        (5, "CONSULTANTDOCTOR"),
        (6, "JUNIORDOCTOR"),
        (7, "STRYVSAGENT"),
        (9, "SERVICEPROVIDER"),
        (10, "DOCTORASSISTANT"),
    )

    hospital = models.ForeignKey(Hospital, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey("Doctor", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.IntegerField(choices=ROLES, null=True, blank=True)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    permissions = models.ManyToManyField(StaffPermissions, blank=True)


class Doctor(TimeStampedModel):
    """
    This table stores all the information related to Staff,
    Should be called STAFF but not renaming it to avoid complexities
    Store information of doctors, a doctor can specialize in
    multiple departments and visit multiple hospitals
    """

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # profile_image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=127)
    is_visible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admitting_officer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    practice_started_year = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1023)
    about_hi = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=1023)
    credentials = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    departments = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    hospitals = models.ManyToManyField(Hospital)  # This shall be removed
    hospital_doctors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Hospital, through="HospitalDoctor", related_name="hospital_doctors"
    )
    appointment_types = models.ManyToManyField("appointments.AppointmentTypes")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here's the serializers:-

```
class PermissionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Permission model's serializer
    """
    class Meta:
        model = StaffPermissions
        fields = ['ui_element','create','read','update','delete',]

class DoctorHospitalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serilizer for Hospital Model
    A new serializer is used because less fields are required
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
        fields = (
            "id",
            "name",
        )

class HospitalDoctorSerializer2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for intermediary model.
    """
    permissions = PermissionSerializer(write_only = True)

    class Meta:
        model = HospitalDoctor
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self,validated_data):
        hospital_doctor_obj = super().create(validated_data)
        permissions = validated_data.pop("permissions")
        for permission_data in permissions:
            permission_serializer = StaffPermissions(data = permission_data)
            permission_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
            permission_serializer.save()
            permissions_obj = permission_serializer.instance
            hospital_doctor_obj.permissions.add(permissions_obj)
        hospital_doctor_obj.save()
        return hospital_doctor_obj

class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for viewing entries Doctor model
    """

    hospital_doctors = HospitalDoctorSerializer2(many = True,write_only = True)
    departments_display = DepartmentSerializer(
        many=True, source="departments", read_only=True
    )
    appointment_types_display = AppointmentTypeSerializer(
        many=True, source="appointment_types", read_only=True
    )
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        exclude = ("hospitals",)
        extra_kwargs = {
            "departments": {"write_only": True},
            "appointment_types": {"required": False},
        }


    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Doctor` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user_data = validated_data.pop("user")
                hospital_doctor_data = validated_data.pop("hospital_doctors")
               # hospital_doctor_serializer = HospitalDoctorSerializer2(data = hospital_doctor_data)
                #hospital_doctor_serializer.is_valid()
                #hospital_data = validated_data.pop("hospitals")
                serializer = UserSerializer(data=user_data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                user = serializer.instance
                validated_data["user"] = user
                #hospital_doctor_serializer.save()
                doc_obj = super().create(validated_data)
              ##  hospital_obj = doc_obj.hospitals
                for hospital_doctor in hospital_doctor_data:
                    hospital_doctor["doctor"] = doc_obj.id
                    hospital_doctor_serializer = HospitalDoctorSerializer2(data = hospital_doctor)
                    hospital_doctor_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                    hospital_doctor_serializer.save()
                    hospital_doc_obj = hospital_doctor_serializer.instance
                    doc_obj.hospital_doctors.add(hospital_doc_obj)
                doc_obj.save
                return doc_obj
    


        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This user is already registered")
        #except Exception as e:
            raise APIException()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question seems incomplete to me. Would you please describe "when" this is the error thrown?

Comment: apologies for that, i have updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing the object directly.

Instead, try passing `id` in the serializer:

```
def create(self,validated_data):
        hospital_doctor_obj = super().create(validated_data)
        permissions = validated_data.pop("permissions")
        for permission_data in permissions:
            permission_serializer = StaffPermissions(data = permission_data)
            permission_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
            permission_serializer.save()
            permissions_obj = permission_serializer.instance
            hospital_doctor_obj.permissions.add(permissions_obj.id)
        hospital_doctor_obj.save()
        return hospital_doctor_obj
```

See the change in `hospital_doctor_obj.permissions.add(permissions_obj.id)`.